# Instalação do Android Studio no Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar instalar o Android Studio no Windows 10. Ao completar a instalação as informações na tela aparecem em inglês(nos botões) e em uma linguagem desconfigurada nos demais locais. Alguém já passou por esse problema, e sabe como solucioná-lo? Ou alguma outra opção de instalação no Windows 10?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E o que acontece depois que você clica na primeira opção? (De criar novo projeto)

Answer (score 0):

Já passei por algo similar no Chrome. Isso possivelmente é causado pelo computador estar com vírus ou com entradas do registro corrompido.

A forma mais simples de resolver e mais rápida, acredito que seja formatando a maquina e instalando o Studio do 0.